# Image de un Card Bootstrap en Laravel

Tags: laravel, bootstrap

Estoy programando en Laravel y he utilizado un card bootstrap. He colcado una imagen al card y al recargar la pagina en el navegador no muestra la imagen. Que puede estar pasando? img/guntherrall.jpg estan dentro de la misma carpeta donde se ubica el archivo php que contiene este código.

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
<img src="img/guntherrall.jpg" class="card-img-top img-fluidS">
<div class="card-body">
  <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
  <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Abre la consola del navegador y checa si obtienes algún error

Comment: @BetaM la consola me presenta estos errores: Region.jsm:                   Error fetching region DOMException: The operation was aborted. Region.jsm:350:11
    _getRegion resource://gre/modules/Region.jsm:350
Region.jsm: Failed to fetch region Error: NO_RESULT
    _getRegion resource://gre/modules/Region.jsm:351
Region.jsm:154:11
    _fetchRegion resource://gre/modules/Region.jsm:154

Comment: Region.jsm:Error fetching region DOMException: The operation was aborted.                                                                                            _getRegion resource://gre/modules/Region.jsm:350                                    Region.jsm: Failed to fetch region Error: NO_RESULT                             _getRegion resource://gre/modules/Region.jsm:351

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel tiene estructura de carpetas

La imagen no debe de estar en el mismo directorio (carpeta) que tu archivo php de tu código, yo la pondría en public/img/guntherrall.jpg y utilizaría lo que te sugirieron:

```
<img src="{{asset('img/guntherrall.jpg')}}" class="card-img-top img-fluid">
```

Comment: te refieres a storage/app/public?

Comment: si estas trabajando local es directamente en tuproyecto/public/img/guntherrall.jpg y si es en produccion public_html/img/guntherrall.jpg

Comment: si funcionó tu sugerencia,  img/guntherrall.jpg la coloqué en public y la línea `<img src="{{asset('img/guntherrall.jpg')}}" class="card-img-top img-fluid">`. Mil gracias.

Comment: Muy bien, que bueno que te funciono, estoy para ayudar en lo que pueda.

Comment: Gracias @Gouk igualmente para servir.